# Python Pandas: get max index within groupby object?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my `groupby` result after aggregation:

```
                Message
Month   Hour    
    1   0        192
        1        152
        2        64
        3        117
        4        59
        5        15
        6        73
        7        53
        8        33
        9        116
        10       219
        11       264
        12       686
        13       878
        14       320
        15       287
        16       447
        17       792
        18       886
        19       861
        20       458
        21       375
        22       434
        23       238
    2   0         49
        1         25
        2         23
        3         15
        6         45
        7         23
        .         
        .         
        .
```

I want to get the `Hour` which has maximum number of `Message` in the `Month`.

For example, in January, I want to get `18` which has the highest msg count.

How can I implement it in a code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html), but it return tuples because `MultiIndex`, so need `str[1]` for select second values:

```
s = df.groupby(level=0)['Message'].idxmax().str[1]
print (s)
Month
1    18
2     0
Name: Message, dtype: int64
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby(level=0)['Message'].idxmax())
Month
1    (1, 18)
2     (2, 0)
Name: Message, dtype: object
```

Another solution is create column by first level of `MultiIndex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.reset_index(level=0).groupby('Month')['Message'].idxmax())
Month
1    18
2     0
Name: Message, dtype: int64
```